# How to search strings in java

Tags: java, sql, string, search, plsql

I currently search the database to get certain results with a pl/sql query like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
citrostats cs
WHERE
(
trim(upper(cs.name)) like trim(upper('%'|| ? ||'%'))
OR
trim(upper(cs.UCODE)) like trim(upper('%'|| ? ||'%'))
)
ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

I reorganised this, and fetched all rows into Lists of Objects with have the respective columns as String attributes.

What I need is a java code that would search attributes that are String type to give the same set of objects as results like this query has.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What exactly does the 'trim' do in this SQL? Seems to be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

There is [String#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
 if (name.toUpperCase().contains(uppercasedSearchString))
```

Since you are doing this in a loop, save work by upper-casing the search string only once before the loop.